# How to set inflation for tokens?

Tags: inflation, token, ico

I'd like to create a Stellar token and would like to use it as shares for a startup I'm working on so the whole idea is to reward early investors in the ICO with a fixed yearly dividend so inflation looks like a good option. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is possible according to the stellar [blog](https://www.stellar.org/blog/tokens-on-stellar/):

> Inflate token supply in a predefined schedule using [pre-authorized transactions](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#pre-authorized-transaction)
>
> Issue a dividend

In step 1, an issuing account is created. This is the account that can create tokens and send them out. But, notice in the end of the article (step 6) they lock the account, so that the supply is limited. If you want to be able to create inflation, simply do not lock the issuing account.

Comment: Does it make sense to copy the summarizing bullet points from the blog post so that they live in this thread (in case the link is broken down the line)?

Comment: Is it possible to inflate at a predefined rate while guaranteeing you won't inflate by more? If you do not lock the issuing account, you'd be able to inflate by any amount. What if you'd only like to inflate by 100 tokens each year and never more than that? Is that doable?